# ActiveDataProvider:"query" property must be instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions

i am using an self-defined func that encapsu findBySql() to return rows .but got the error showed in the title. but if i test to use self-defined func that encapsu find() ,it worked,why?

Here is my action:

```
public function actionList()
{
     $model = new Loan();
     $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(
     [
        'query' => $model->findValid($_GET['type']),//error comes here
        'pagination' => [
                        'pagesize' => '2',
         ],
     ]);

      return $this->renderPartial('list', ['model' => $model, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

Here is the object loan's findxx function:

```
 public function findValid($type=null)
{
    if($type==null){
            return static::findBySql("select * from loan where wmstat&1=1 and (wmstat>>2)&1=0")->all();
    }else{
            return static::findBySql("select * from loan where wmstat&1=1 and (wmstat>>2)&1=0 and origin="."'".$type."'")->all();
    }
}
```

Futher more,can i change the bit operatin using find() and where() and achieve the same effect ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is clear, `query` expects valid query instance, while you are passing results of query and not the query itself.

Remove `->all()` calls in `findValid()` method and it should work.

**P.S.** I strongly recommend to refactor your code to better condition.

**Official docs:**

- [ActiveDataProvider $query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html#$query-detail)
- [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html)
- [findBySql()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one with basic code example; not using `->all()`

```
$query = User::find(); 
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' =>5],
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```